# Windows users can see a strange letter (a white dot on black background) on text originally typed on a MacBook

Tags: macos, text, internationalization, input-source, unicode

I and my colleagues happened to see a strange letter appearing randomly in texts typed by another colleague who uses a MacBook and with the "Simple Telex" input method used for their keyboard setting. The random character appears as a white dot on a black background (see image below).

It can appear anywhere (in Excel, a blog post, etc).

Has anyone else encountered this? Any suggestions on how to avoid it?

[image]

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Just curious, has your colleague tried using the "Telex" input method instead just to see if the problem also appears with that?

Comment: Please copy/paste one of these characters into the text of your question (not an image) so we can see what codepoint it is.

Comment: Here's the text: "Đối với trẻ nhỏ dưới 2 tuổi, hệ thống này chủ yếu dành cho những người chăm sóc bé".

the character is infrontof "hệ thống".

My colleague use "simple telex" on default macbook typing utility.

I can see that when I paste the texts, the special character is also pasted and present in those texts. But affter saving this comment, when i edit the comment, in the box, the special character disappeared.

Comment: Here's also the link to the website that has the character that i've mention above: https://thepresentwriter.com/minimalism-baby-toi-gian-khi-co-tre-nho-phan-1/

Comment: Could you isolate this character and increase the font size to something very large and post an image of that here?

Comment: Here it is: https://imgur.com/C2ZPWFj

Comment: One problem I think is that we are all mac users and can't even see the character you are talking about to analyze it  Try copy/pasting that sentence in a email to me (thgewecke at gmail dot com)  Also your picture of it is still 10 times too small.